# Non-trivial counterexample for R-linear convergence implies Q-linear convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm sure this is a straightforward question, but I can't seem to find a non-trivial counterexample.

Let $\{\phi_k\}\subset \mathbb{R}^{\geqslant 0}$ such that $\phi_k\to 0$. Defining R-linear and Q-linear convergence respectively as
$$
\exists\sigma\in(0,1),C\in\mathbb{R}\,\,\text{s.t.} \phi_k\leqslant C(1-\sigma)^k \,\,\forall k \\
\exists\sigma\in(0,1)\,\,\text{s.t. }\frac{\phi_{k+1}}{\phi_k}\leqslant 1-\sigma\,\, \forall k
$$
I am seeking counterexamples to R-linear implies Q-linear, with the only example I can think of being $\phi_k=0$ for all $k$ (interpreting the ratio as $1$). In words I'm seeking a sequence which tends to $0$ faster than a multiple of a geometric sequence, but with ratio tending to $1$. I'm sure I'm missing some easy examples here...

Edit: My counterexample doesn't even make sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your precise statements, the following is a counterexample:
$$\phi_k = 2^{-\lceil k/2\rceil}.$$
We have
$$\phi_k \le 2^{-k/2} = 1 \cdot \left(1 - \sigma\right)^k,$$
where
$$\sigma = 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \in (0, 1).$$
That is, $\phi_k$ is R-linear. But,
$$\frac{\phi_{2k}}{\phi_{2k-1}} = \frac{2^{-\lceil 2k/2\rceil}}{2^{-\lceil (2k-1)/2\rceil}} = \frac{2^{-k}}{2^{-k}} = 1,$$
so $\phi_k$ is not Q-linear.

Note that the ratio does not tend to $1$; it's not hard to see that $\phi_{2k+1}/\phi_{2k} = \frac{1}{2}$ instead. Indeed, if you wanted $\phi_{k+1}/\phi_k \to 1$ (or anything greater) as $k \to \infty$, then it would be impossible for $\phi_k$ to be R-linear.

Comment: Great! I had an inkling that some kind of occasionally 'repeating' sequence could work. Your example has inspired me to think of the example $\phi_k=4^{-m}$ for $k=2m-1,2m$. Then $\phi_k\leqslant 2^{-k}=(1-\frac{1}{2})^{k}$ yet the ratio alternates between $1$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ (the same idea but it feels clearer to me). Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: You're welcome! I don't really follow your example, but I think you just mis-typed it, and I think you know what you're doing.